# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010 while using blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
- (void)getFromWebwithCompletionBlock:(ResponseCallback)completionBlock
{
   [/*
   .... network call
   */
   {
       completionBlock();
   }];
}


Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
0  asd                       0x1001dc2cc __69-[Engine getFromWebwithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke (Engine.m:200)
1  asd                       0x10010f4d8 -[NetworkCallService sendResponseForCall:] (NetworkCallService.m:422)
2  asd                       0x10010f008 -[NetworkCallService respondSuccessWithData:responseData:] (NetworkCallService.m:396)
3  asd                       0x10010e778 __43-[NetworkCallService connectWithRequest:]_block_invoke_2 (NetworkCallService.m:337)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x193f39994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x193f39954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x193f3e20c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1820cb7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1820c98a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181ff52d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
10 GraphicsServices               0x18b8136fc GSEventRunModal + 168
11 UIKit                          0x186bbafac UIApplicationMain + 1488
12 Mobikwik                       0x1000c8fcc main (main.m:16)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x193f66a08 start + 4
```

as far as i got from other stackoverflow posts my completionBlock is getting released before execution. My doubt here is if i am passing my completionBlock as an argument to the function, How can it be deallocated?

Isn’t my function’s class retaining the block? I am currently going to fix it by checking if completionBlock is nil, but i would like to know how can it ever be nil

Comment: create a singleton network class and then use this function inside that class.. it will ensure that created instance.. if there is some.. working already so it is possible it gets destroyed

Comment: @magid i create a new object of network class for each call. Basically its a wrapper around [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:]. I am not sure if your solution would do anything. If you think otherwise please explain as an answer.

Comment: This all depends on the code that you've commented out. What happens to the `{
       completionBlock();
   }` part while your `Engine` goes off and does the network stuff?

Comment: @JoshCaswell i dont do anything with the completionBlock during that time. Litterally nothing. I just create a NSURLConnection Object and make the call, once the call returns i parse the data and return the data to completionBlock.